# Git GUI: how to change the locale

Tags: git, locale

On my German Windows, when launching `git gui` it occurs in hard-to-understand German. How can I change it to the default English? The Git GUI options menu item does not offer such an option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just set the environment variable `LANG` to the value `en_US`.

Comment: or... LANG=C LANGUAGE=C will always fall back to standard C locale (which will not require any locales on your system). You might miss some 'niceties' in the en_US[.UTF8] locales, but it will work; git is charset agnostic, so it won't hurt

Comment: Can someone confirm this actually fixes the problem?  The OP is asking about forcing `git gui` on Windows to `en_US`.  I tried the opposite, forcing `set LANG=de_DE`, and it dot NOT force `git gui` to German.  Using `2.14.1.windows`.

Answer (score 8):

Just guessing: if it uses localization files, you can either delete German localization file (it most probably will fallback to English) or create duplicate of English and replace German with it.

Comment: woah. deleting the locale files. crappy advice IMHO

Comment: That was just guessing, considering user tried and haven't found a way to do it 'legally' (> "The Git GUI options menu item does not offer such an option").

Comment: Worked for me. Just as advice: The path to the language file is `<GIT-install-dir>\share\git-gui\lib\msgs\<your-lang>.msg` for Windows 64Bit. I simply renamed it so I can fall back to this one day.

Comment: Worked like a charm, deleted Russian.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question and I am aware that the proper answer has already been given and accepted, but in case someone skips it and decides to go with Petr Abdulin's approach (because the accepted answer didn't work for them, they didn't want to change their `LANG` environment variable...), adding an extra extension to the currently used translation (not always common sense) will also work in this specific situation - making your system fallback to English **and** keep your non-English translation file intact.

When doing things in such a way, you always want to keep a backup of the original files, even if you think you will never ever need them again or assume it will automatically work just because it works in most situations. Don't copy files and blindly replace. Assume this will not work and you may need to retrieve your original file back without major hassle.

The choice for the extension is up to you. For German translations:

```
de.msg -> de.msg.bak (do not use .bak if it conflicts with auto-backups)
de.msg -> de.msg.original (non-standard, but slightly more intuitive)
```

To cancel the fallback process, simply remove the additional extension.

```
de.msg.bak -> de.msg
```

If you can properly set your configuration, don't touch the files and do that instead.

Only use this quickfix of your issue as a workaround for what you should actually do.