# How does one change the language of the command line interface of Git?

Tags: bash, git, localization, environment-variables, locale

I’d like to change the language of git (to English) in my Linux installation without changing the language for other programs and couldn’t find the settings.
How to do it?

Comment: You're looking to change locale. I'd repost that question on superuser I think.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

Add these lines to your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zprofile` to force git to display all messages in English:

```
# Set Git language to English
#alias git='LANG=en_US git'
alias git='LANG=en_GB git'
```

The alias needs to override `LC_ALL` on some systems, when the environment variable `LC_ALL` is set, which has precedence over `LANG`. See the [UNIX Specification - Environment Variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html) for further explanation.

```
# Set Git language to English
#alias git='LC_ALL=en_US git'
alias git='LC_ALL=en_GB git'
```

In case you added these lines to `~/.bashrc` the alias will be defined when a new interactive shell gets started. In case you added it to `~/.bash_profile` the alias will be applied when logging in.

Comment: There was a typo in the file name (`.bash.rc` instead of `.bashrc`). You also have to close and start the shell again for the `.bashrc` to be executed. I added an note on this, as well.

Comment: I tried it in my `.bashrc` even with restarting. Aliases work. It´s just the language doesn´t change.

Comment: To verify that the `.bashrc` gets executed successfully you could add an test like `echo "This is .bashrc"`to the end of the file. You can also get have it executed on demand without having to restart the terminal or the whole system by `. .bashrc`. Finally, I would suggest trying to set the `LC_ALL` environment variable instead of `LANG`, since the first one has precedence.

Comment: Everything is fine with my `.bashrc`, really.
If `LC_ALL` has precedence then this will be the problem, it is set to my language. But then I don´t want to change the general language setting... Can´t I overwrite it for one program?

Comment: You can set the language using the suggested method without side effects, since these variables only life as long as the command takes to terminate. Try it by running `$ LC_ALL="en_US" man` and then `$ man`

Comment: Ok, `alias git='LC_ALL="en_US" git'` works! Would you please extend your answer to include both cases with explanation?

Comment: Glad I could finally help you, I extended my answer accordingly. I guess I have just owned my first acceptance, am I right?

Comment: Yes. But the problem lines in my `.bashrc` were `export LANG="<lang>.UTF-8"` and `export LC_ALL="<lang>.UTF-8"`. So the corresponding one should be overwritten, `LANG` when only `LANG` is set and `LC_ALL` when `LC_ALL` or others are set if I am right.

Comment: Git started to speak French after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10. Setting LANG solved the issue, LC_ALL was unset.

Comment: which directory do you find these files?

Comment: @OliverWatkins `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are located in the home directory. When you open a terminal, you usually are there already. Alternatively, you can do a `cd ~` or `cd $HOME` to get there. I have edited my answer to include `~/` prefixes.

Comment: In case you are using Z shell (zsh) you need to set your language environment to your `~/.zshrc`

Comment: @benedikt The question is about only changing the language of only git. If zsh can do that, that should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 28):

If you just want to have one command in english instead you can just write `LC_ALL=C` before the command, for example:

```
LC_ALL=C git status
```

will result in

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

The locale as used in `C` is English and always available without installing additional language packs
 (see https://askubuntu.com/a/142814/34298)

To change it for the whole current bash session just enter

```
LANG=C
```

To change it for example to german enter

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
```

Comment: Thanks for the `LC_ALL=C` suggestion, as I have some problems with locale, `LC_ALL="en_US"` didn´t work anymore recently.

Answer (score 25):

Adding this line solved the problem for me:
Update: it seems like more components require a Locale as well now.

$ more ~/.bash_profile

> export LANG=en_US (obsolete)

export LANG="en_US.UTF-8" (Updated)

Comment: The question is how to change the language for git only - I updated it to be more clear.

Comment: Missing the encoding, it messed up my environment so bad 

Answer (score 9):

Note: since Git 2.3.1+ (Q1/Q2 2015), Git will add Accept-Language header if possible.
See [commit f18604b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f18604bbf2c391c689a41fca14cbaeff5e106255) by [Yi EungJun (`eungjun-yi`)](https://github.com/eungjun-yi)

> Add an `Accept-Language` header which indicates the user's preferred
> languages defined by `$LANGUAGE`, `$LC_ALL`, `$LC_MESSAGES` and `$LANG`.
>
> This gives git servers a chance to display remote error messages in
> the user's preferred language.

---

You have [locale for git gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089435/git-gui-how-to-change-the-locale) or [other GUIs](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools), <del>but not for the command-line, considering it was one of the questions of [GitSurvey 2010](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSurvey2010)</del>

```
localization of command-line messages (i18n)    258     3.6%
```

Of course, since 2010, as **[`po/README`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/po/README)** describes:

> Before strings can be translated they first have to be marked for translation.
>
> **Git uses an internationalization interface that wraps the system's
> [`gettext`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) library**, so most of the advice in your gettext documentation
> (on GNU systems `info gettext` in a terminal) applies.

In place since [git 1.7.9+](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.9.txt) (January 2012):

> **Git uses `gettext` to translate its most common interface messages into the user's language if translations are available and the locale is appropriately set**.
> Distributors can drop new `PO` files in `po/` to add new translations.

So, if your update has mess up the translation, check what `gettext` uses:
See, for instance, "[Locale Environment Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Locale-Environment-Variables)"

> A locale is composed of several locale categories, see Aspects. When a program looks up locale dependent values, it does this according to the following environment variables, in priority order:
>
> ```
> LANGUAGE
> LC_ALL
> LC_xxx, according to selected locale category: LC_CTYPE, LC_NUMERIC, LC_TIME, LC_COLLATE, LC_MONETARY, LC_MESSAGES, ...
> LANG
> ```
>
> Variables whose value is set but is empty are ignored in this lookup.
>
> `LANG` is the normal environment variable for specifying a locale. As a user, you normally set this variable (unless some of the other variables have already been set by the system, in `/etc/profile` or similar initialization files).
>
> `LC_CTYPE`, `LC_NUMERIC`, `LC_TIME`, `LC_COLLATE`, `LC_MONETARY`, `LC_MESSAGES`, and so on, are the environment variables meant to override `LANG` and affecting a single locale category only.
> For example, assume you are a Swedish user in Spain, and you want your programs to handle numbers and dates according to Spanish conventions, and only the messages should be in Swedish. Then you could create a locale named ‘`sv_ES`’ or ‘`sv_ES.UTF-8`’ by use of the `localedef` program. But it is simpler, and achieves the same effect, to set the `LANG` variable to `es_ES.UTF-8` and the `LC_MESSAGES` variable to `sv_SE.UTF-8`; these two locales come already preinstalled with the operating system.
>
> `LC_ALL` is an environment variable that overrides all of these. It is typically used in scripts that run particular programs. For example, configure scripts generated by GNU `autoconf` use `LC_ALL` to make sure that the configuration tests don't operate in locale dependent ways.
>
> Some systems, unfortunately, set `LC_ALL` in `/etc/profile` or in similar initialization files. As a user, you therefore have to unset this variable if you want to set `LANG` and optionally some of the other `LC_xxx` variables.

---

Earlier, HTTP transport clients learned to tell the server side what locale they are in by sending `Accept-Language` HTTP header, but this was done only for some requests but not others.
This is fixed with Git 2.38 (Q3 2022):

See [commit b0c4adc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0c4adcdd7e339110bea8da94d7880d413e49330) (11 Jul 2022) by [Li Linchao (`Cactusinhand`)](https://github.com/Cactusinhand).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4b8cdff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4b8cdff8baa44c97a784d5b4b6c5a9df37de41ff), 19 Jul 2022)</sup>

> ### [`remote-curl`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0c4adcdd7e339110bea8da94d7880d413e49330): send Accept-Language header to server
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Li Linchao</sup>

> Git server end's ability to accept `Accept-Language` header was introduced in [f18604b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f18604bbf2c391c689a41fca14cbaeff5e106255) ("`http`: add Accept-Language header if possible", 2015-01-28, Git v2.4.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f18e3896f7e3fd8de060aa37d9e35387a3b9282b)), but this is only used by very early phase of the transfer, which is HTTP `GET` request to discover references.
> For other phases, like `POST` request in the smart HTTP, the server does not know what language the client speaks.
>
> Teach git client to learn end-users preferred language and throw `accept-language` header to the server side.
> Once the server gets this header, it has the ability to talk to end-user with language they understand.
> This would be very helpful for many non-English speakers.

Comment: So where does the transalation come from? The reason why I asked is that I had git in english before and after an update it changed to my language, but I don´t like this.

Comment: @user905686 sorry, my mistake. Git supports locale, with gettext. So check out your environment variables. I detail which one to check in my edited answer.

Comment: What if I want to just change the language for git but not for other programs? I.e. for me translations break some things so I would like to have git *always* (no matter which program calls it) have LANG=C and everything else in my native language. Any ideas?

Comment: @Droggl As long as you set `LANG` in the bash/shell/DOS session you are using `git` in (or launching `git-gui` from), only `git` (or `git-gui`) will be using that specific setting. All the other programs will inherit from the system / user environment variables.

Answer (score 9):

Run `LC_MESSAGES=C git`, not LC_ALL=C or LANG=C and no need delete or rename files.

This command change output Git messages to english.

Answer (score 4):

As Bengt suggested : Add these lines to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` to force git to display all messages in English:
`vim ~/.bashrc` - for this profile (if you are user `ubuntu` and you edit this it will be only for this user);
add this lines:

```
# Set Git language to English
#alias git='LANG=en_US git'
alias git='LANG=en_GB git'
#you can add also 
LANG=en_GB
```

and after you close the file you need to write in shell:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

to reload new settings or exit the terminal and connect again :)

Comment: What is the additional `LANG=en_GB` in `~/.bashrc` supposed to do? Doesn't that just define the local variable `LANG`?

Answer (score 3):

GIT defaults to english if it cannot find the Locale language.

So if you want GIT to be in english, just sabotage the language file that it is running with. In my case it was always running with german (ie: **de.msg**).

If I deleted it or renamed the it, then it defaulted to english.

[image]

Here I renamed the file

[image]

Comment: With Git for Windows 2.x (64 bit) this will be in `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\share\locale\$LANG\LC_MESSAGES\git.mo`.

Comment: The advantage of this approach might be that after an update of git, the translation will be back (and maybe improved), so you can decide again whether you want to use it or remove it again.

Comment: I've checked the source code, it seems that git does not support English: https://github.com/git-l10n/git-po/tree/master/po  Even I want to use English first before Chinese and Swedish (en_GB:en:zh_HK:zh_CN:zh:sv_SE:sv), git still shows Chinese to me.

Comment: On Mac OSx with Git installed via Homebrew, I found the locales in `/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.21.0/share/locale/`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to change git language follow answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10872202/5381331) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12993/why-doesnt-bashrc-run-automatically)

1) `nano ~/.bashrc` 
2) add `alias git='LANG=en_GB git'` to the file  
2) save the file 
4) `source ~/.bashrc`

Now your git already change the language. However, **IF** after your restart terminal and it not working anymore, you need to

4.1) `nano ~/.profile` 
4.2) add `source ~/.bashrc` 
4.3) save the file

it will make `source ~/.bashrc` run whenever you open the terminal

Hope it help