# Can git use a different locale on a remote server?

Tags: git, localization, gitolite

I have gitolite running on a remote server (in English_US) and one of my computers accesses it using git with es_MX (español, Mexico) as the locale. Everytime I access the server, it gives me an error:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "es_MX.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

Is there a way to tell git to use en_US when connecting to gitolite only?

**Edit:**
I have already tried the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633564/how-does-one-change-the-language-of-the-command-line-interface-of-git), but that only changes the local language, and does not affect the error.

Answer (score 0):

That might means the [locale aren't properly set up on your gitolite server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2499826/6309)

```
$ sudo locale-gen
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

And/or that [your sshd doesn't accept the LANG environment variable (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2510548/6309):

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```