# Git messages in English (in all applications, not bash only)

Tags: git, localization, git-config

I am currently using Emacs + Magit, but I guess my question is more general than the specific use of these software. I've read [How does one change the language of the command line interface of Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633564/how-does-one-change-the-language-of-the-command-line-interface-of-git) on SO, but it only gives an appropriate answer for the use of Git CLI in a bash.

My question is thus simple: Is there a solution to use a specific locale (in my case `en_US`) for Git to use in every application, in particular outside of the bash?

For the case of Magit, there is a [workaround from within Emacs](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1275), but it still creates other problems (e.g. starting R/ESS from Emacs, I now get warnings such as: "1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C"").

I checked the doc for [git-config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) and [the configuration of Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration), but I could not find anything related to localization. I was actually looking for something similar as `lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8'` that you can use with PostgreSQL (in `postgresql.conf`), and found it surprising that there does not seem to be a similar approach for Git.

---

**Edit:** The question here is really about changing the specific locale of Git, and only Git, and outside of a shell. For instance, running `LANG=en_US emacs` in a shell, as suggested by michas, set the locale for all applications run in the shell and, obviously, involves a shell. I'm really looking for a solution similar to the approach of PostgreSQL, e.g. via configuration files.

---

**Edit2:** My system is Debian Jessie (current testing), with `fr_FR` as default locale, and do include `en_US` in the list of locales:

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
fr_CA.utf8
fr_FR.utf8
POSIX
```

Comment: What distribution are you using? Does `locale -a` list `en_US`?

Comment: I should have state it in the first place: Debian Jessie (currently testing). `en_US` is in the list of locales--it really is not a problem of locales on my system, but how to make sure that only git is using `en_US`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your locale properly.

Type `locale -a` to show all available locales.

Type `locale` to show you current setting.

You have different ways to set your locale. Either set it from your shell when starting your application like `LANG=en_US emacs` or you set it for all command of your shell using `export LANG=en_US`.

If you want to change the locale for your whole system you can set some system config file, but this is distribution specific.

Be aware that `locale -a` must list `en_US` to be able to use this locale. The generation of locales is also distribution specific.

Comment: Thanks michas for your answer. I should have been more specific: I just want to change the locale of Git, not the whole system (which is currently in French [FR], and I want it to stay like that). Turning Git in English is a must have for documentation/debugging and for collaboration. Using `LANG=en_US emacs` from the shell is not the best option, since I never run it from the shell (as a matter of fact, Emacs itself is already in English on my system...). I completed my original question.

Comment: If you don't run emacs from shell, how do you start it? There is probably some kind of starter which you can configure to run your emacs using the custom locale. Running emacs in french but git in english will require support from magit.

Comment: Well, the most common way I start Emacs is directly from a file, with file association (or Open with...). I might also run Emacs always in `en_US`, but then every subprocess within Emacs will be in `en_US` too, which I'd like to avoid. Ideally, I'd like to have a fine-grained setup with Git only in `en_US`, independently of the rest. The solution with Magit is linked in my initial post, but does not solve the problem properly.