# Where can I find a list of languages that Git is localized to?

Tags: git, localization

My `LANG` is set to `sv_SE.UTF-8` but I don't see any difference in any messages when I use git (everything is in English). That's why I want to know which languages are available in the latest version, as well as for my version if possible (`git version 2.3.8 (Apple Git-58)`).

I couldn't find anything when searching on git-scm.com

Comment: are you sure you `export`ed the variable correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'll be sure to investigate it now that I know that the language exists

Comment: @KurzedMetal `export` lists `declare -x LANG="sv_SE.UTF-8"` so I think it is exported... But I suppose that is best handled in a new question.

Comment: Yeah, that means it is exported correctly, try setting `LC_ALL` too, check [this post about localization](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10872202/236871)

Comment: No luck. `LC_ALL` wasn't set (nor any other `LC_`), and `export LC_ALL=$LANG` didn't make any difference. I have to investigate this "Apple Git" business to solve it I think

Comment: Problem found. The latest Git installer README for OSX says: `Since Mac OS X does not ship with gettext, this build does not
  include gettext support. If popular demand requests (via the git
  issue tracker
  http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/issues/list) the
  installer may bundle gettext in the future to provide localization
  support`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the available gettext PO files in the Git repository: https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/po

There's an [l10n README.md](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/po/README.md) in that directory too