# Git add old commit to current branch and do a PR

Tags: git, github

I have a current branch which starts from `master`.

The branch is called: `development`

So I did:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git branch development
git cherry-pick XXXX
```

but it returns `it's a fusion but option -m was not provided.`

My goal is to recover an specific commit I did 25 days ago, in my current branch and do a PR with just these old changes. Back in the days it failed due to an error in the server.

Comment: "it's a fusion" doesn't sound like a git error message. Are you trying to translate from a non-English message? If that's the case then you can use `LC_ALL=en_US git cherry-pick XXXX` to get the English error message for ease of Googling (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633564/how-does-one-change-the-language-of-the-command-line-interface-of-git)).

Comment: Exactly! Now it returns: is a merge but no -m option was given.

Comment: Please accept the duplicate flag